# Select people who like to eat burgers and who like to paint. - means I should select people who like to do both?

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses

**Example 1**

> Select people who like to eat burgers and who like to paint.

**Example 2**

> Select people who like to eat burgers and like to paint.

Do they mean the same?

I think Example 1 can mean I am allowed to select people who only like to eat burgers or people who only like to paint.

However, Example 2, to me, means that I can only select people who like both eating burgers and painting. Example 1 can probably be interpreted this way as well.

Comment: Both versions are potentially ambiguous, but #2 is more *likely* to be interpreted as "inclusive" (i.e. - only select people who meet *both* criteria). In a real-world *spoken* context, you'd encourage that interpretation even more strongly by placing heavy stress on ***and***, but even that wouldn't *completely* remove the ambiguity. To do that, you'd need something more like *Select people who like to **both** eat burgers and paint* (with optional heavy stress on ***and*** if you specifically want to *emphasize* the intended sense, *in addition* to being "non-ambiguous").

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I add definite articles to before the two examples, does that influence the interpretation? For example, #1 "Select the students who like to eat burgers and who like to paint." and #2 "Select the students who like to eat burgers and like to paint."

Comment: You can fiddle around all you like. Most people will say *some* variations entail more (or less) ambiguity than others. But they won't all agree *which* variations are more (or less) ambiguous, so it's not worth spending too much time on it. About the only "bulletproof" disambiguation sticking with the basic sentence structure is the one I gave before  - you put ***both*** immediately before one verb *(**eat**)*, and lay heavy stress on ***and*** before the other verb *(**like** / to paint)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. So, basically, adding a definite article does not really change anything, but using "both" or other means can really impact the meaning, right?

Comment: In the real world, when real people speak to each other, their main purpose is to be clearly understood. Your sentences would be considered unclear. Suppose I run a dating agency. I can try to find you a partner with features you specify. You say 'choose me someone from people who like to eat burgers and who like to paint.' I will immediately ask (because I don't want any trouble later when I ask you to pay the bill) 'Do you mean both, or either?'

Comment: Including ***both*** doesn't *automatically* resolve any ambiguity - it depends on exactly where you put it. So it wouldn't really clarify anything if you said *Select only people who like to eat burgers and who like to paint.* Or if you put the word ***only*** right at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

If you use *and* rather than *or*, the implication of both sentences is 'people who like both those things'. To make the meaning absolutely clear, include *both* in the sentence.

Comment: Using ***and*** rather than ***or*** doesn't *unambiguously* force one meaning or the other for me, with OP's example. Apart from anything else, though, there's the possibility that ***or*** means *EITHER **all** the selected people must meet criterion #1 OR they must all meet criterion #2* That's to say - you can't have a mixture of type #1 and type #2 people (and *feasibly*, you can't even include any *individuals* who meet both criteria! :).

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers says in his comments, both sentences are ambiguous. Adding a second "who" doesn't really resolve the ambiguity.

To be clear, you should say something like, "select people who like to eat burgers and who also like to paint" if you mean that both criteria must apply to each person. Or, "select people who like to eat burgers, and also select people who like to paint" if you mean you want two sets of people.

This kind of ambiguity is often used for the punch line of jokes. Like I recall a club I was a member of years ago boasting, "More people are members of our club than are Democrats and Republicans combined. Because we took a survey and found that there are very few people who are Democrats and Republicans combined."